# Spark SQL join on closest date by ID

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables below that I'm trying to join based on ID and the closest available `weekly_dt` date based on the `ingest_date` column.

in standard ANSI SQL I usually use a correlated sub query and limit the query to one result per row so there is no aggregate error, however doing this in standard SparkSQL gives me the following error

```
AnalysisException: Correlated scalar subqueries must be aggregated: GlobalLimit 1
```

#### Setup

---

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

np.random.seed(25)
A1 = [('A1', i.date(), np.random.randint(0,50)) for i in pd.date_range('01 Jan 2021', '21 Jan 2021',freq='D')]
A2 = [('A2', i.date(), np.random.randint(0,50)) for i in pd.date_range('01 Jan 2021', '21 Jan 2021',freq='D')]
```

---

```
df_a = spark.createDataFrame(A1  + A2, ['id','ingest_date','amt'])

weekly_scores = [
    ('A1', pd.Timestamp('01 Jan 2021').date(), '0.5'),
    ('A1', pd.Timestamp('08 Jan 2021').date(), '0.3'),
    ('A1', pd.Timestamp('15 Jan 2021').date(), '0.8'),
    ('A1', pd.Timestamp('22 Jan 2021').date(), '0.6'),
    ('A2', pd.Timestamp('01 Jan 2021').date(), '0.6'),
    ('A2', pd.Timestamp('08 Jan 2021').date(), '0.1'),
    ('A2', pd.Timestamp('15 Jan 2021').date(), '0.9'),
    ('A2', pd.Timestamp('22 Jan 2021').date(), '0.3'),
]

df_b = spark.createDataFrame(weekly_scores, ['id','weekly_dt','score'])
```

#### Tables

---

```
df_a.show()

+---+-----------+---+
| id|ingest_date|amt|
+---+-----------+---+
| A1| 2021-01-01| 26|
| A1| 2021-01-02|  1|
| A1| 2021-01-03|  0|
| A1| 2021-01-04| 31|
| A1| 2021-01-05| 41|
| A1| 2021-01-06| 46|
| A1| 2021-01-07| 11|
| A1| 2021-01-08|  0|
| A1| 2021-01-09| 14|
| A1| 2021-01-10|  5|
| A1| 2021-01-11|  0|
| A1| 2021-01-12| 35|
| A1| 2021-01-13|  5|
| A1| 2021-01-14| 43|
| A1| 2021-01-15| 18|
| A1| 2021-01-16| 31|
| A1| 2021-01-17| 44|
| A1| 2021-01-18| 25|
| A1| 2021-01-19| 47|
| A1| 2021-01-20| 36|
+---+-----------+---+
```

---

```
df_b.show()

+---+----------+-----+
| id| weekly_dt|score|
+---+----------+-----+
| A1|2021-01-01|  0.5|
| A1|2021-01-08|  0.3|
| A1|2021-01-15|  0.8|
| A1|2021-01-22|  0.6|
| A2|2021-01-01|  0.6|
| A2|2021-01-08|  0.1|
| A2|2021-01-15|  0.9|
| A2|2021-01-22|  0.3|
+---+----------+-----+
```

---

#### Expected Output.

```
     id ingest_date  amt  weekly_dt score
0    A1  2021-01-01   26 2021-01-01   0.5
4    A1  2021-01-02    1 2021-01-01   0.5
8    A1  2021-01-03    0 2021-01-01   0.5
12   A1  2021-01-04   31 2021-01-01   0.5
17   A1  2021-01-05   41 2021-01-08   0.3
21   A1  2021-01-06   46 2021-01-08   0.3
25   A1  2021-01-07   11 2021-01-08   0.3
29   A1  2021-01-08    0 2021-01-08   0.3
33   A1  2021-01-09   14 2021-01-08   0.3
37   A1  2021-01-10    5 2021-01-08   0.3
41   A1  2021-01-11    0 2021-01-08   0.3
46   A1  2021-01-12   35 2021-01-15   0.8
50   A1  2021-01-13    5 2021-01-15   0.8
54   A1  2021-01-14   43 2021-01-15   0.8
58   A1  2021-01-15   18 2021-01-15   0.8
62   A1  2021-01-16   31 2021-01-15   0.8
66   A1  2021-01-17   44 2021-01-15   0.8
70   A1  2021-01-18   25 2021-01-15   0.8
75   A1  2021-01-19   47 2021-01-22   0.6
79   A1  2021-01-20   36 2021-01-22   0.6
83   A1  2021-01-21   43 2021-01-22   0.6
84   A2  2021-01-01   32 2021-01-01   0.6
88   A2  2021-01-02   37 2021-01-01   0.6
92   A2  2021-01-03   11 2021-01-01   0.6
96   A2  2021-01-04   21 2021-01-01   0.6
101  A2  2021-01-05   29 2021-01-08   0.1
105  A2  2021-01-06   48 2021-01-08   0.1
109  A2  2021-01-07   12 2021-01-08   0.1
113  A2  2021-01-08   40 2021-01-08   0.1
117  A2  2021-01-09   30 2021-01-08   0.1
121  A2  2021-01-10   28 2021-01-08   0.1
125  A2  2021-01-11   41 2021-01-08   0.1
130  A2  2021-01-12   12 2021-01-15   0.9
134  A2  2021-01-13   10 2021-01-15   0.9
138  A2  2021-01-14   10 2021-01-15   0.9
142  A2  2021-01-15   31 2021-01-15   0.9
146  A2  2021-01-16   13 2021-01-15   0.9
150  A2  2021-01-17   31 2021-01-15   0.9
154  A2  2021-01-18   11 2021-01-15   0.9
159  A2  2021-01-19   15 2021-01-22   0.3
163  A2  2021-01-20   18 2021-01-22   0.3
167  A2  2021-01-21   49 2021-01-22   0.3
```

---

#### `Spark Query`

```
  SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.ingestion_date,
    a.amt,
    b.weekly_dt,
    b.score
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b 
ON a.id = b.id 
AND a.ingestion_date  = 
    (
        SELECT weekly_dt
        FROM b
        WHERE id = b.id 
        ORDER BY DATEDIFF(a.ingest_date, weekly_dt) ASC
        LIMIT 1
    )
```

Edit,

I know I can create a window and use a `dense_rank()` to order the results but I wonder if this is the best method?

```
from pyspark.sql import Window

s = spark.sql("""
SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.ingest_date,
    a.amt,
    b.weekly_dt,
    b.score
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b 
ON b.id = a.id 
""").withColumn('delta', 
                F.abs(F.datediff(F.col('ingest_date'), F.col('weekly_dt')
                                   )
                     )
               )

s.withColumn('t', 
             F.dense_rank().over(
             

Window.partitionBy('id','ingest_date').orderBy(F.asc('delta')))
        ).filter('t == 1').drop('t','delta').show()

    id ingest_date  amt   weekly_dt score
0   A2  2021-01-01   32  2021-01-01   0.6
1   A2  2021-01-02   37  2021-01-01   0.6
2   A2  2021-01-03   11  2021-01-01   0.6
3   A2  2021-01-04   21  2021-01-01   0.6
4   A2  2021-01-05   29  2021-01-08   0.1
5   A2  2021-01-06   48  2021-01-08   0.1
6   A2  2021-01-07   12  2021-01-08   0.1
7   A2  2021-01-08   40  2021-01-08   0.1
8   A2  2021-01-09   30  2021-01-08   0.1
9   A2  2021-01-10   28  2021-01-08   0.1
10  A2  2021-01-11   41  2021-01-08   0.1
11  A2  2021-01-12   12  2021-01-15   0.9
12  A2  2021-01-13   10  2021-01-15   0.9
13  A2  2021-01-14   10  2021-01-15   0.9
14  A2  2021-01-15   31  2021-01-15   0.9
```

Comment: not a dense rank, use a row_number because I think you do not want duplicates ... even if your data does not create duplicate, the logic is not good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would replace the subquery with a limit with a window function :

```py
df = df_a.join(df_b, on="id")

df = (
    df.withColumn(
        "rnk",
        F.row_number().over(
            W.partitionBy("id", "ingest_date").orderBy(
                F.abs(F.datediff("ingest_date", "weekly_dt"))
            )
        ),
    )
    .where("rnk=1")
    .drop("rnk")
)

df.show()
```

```
+---+-----------+---+----------+-----+                                          
| id|ingest_date|amt| weekly_dt|score|
+---+-----------+---+----------+-----+
| A2| 2021-01-01| 31|2021-01-01|  0.6|
| A2| 2021-01-02| 48|2021-01-01|  0.6|
| A2| 2021-01-03| 47|2021-01-01|  0.6|
| A2| 2021-01-04|  9|2021-01-01|  0.6|
| A2| 2021-01-05| 16|2021-01-08|  0.1|
| A2| 2021-01-06| 44|2021-01-08|  0.1|
| A2| 2021-01-07| 45|2021-01-08|  0.1|
| A2| 2021-01-08| 21|2021-01-08|  0.1|
| A2| 2021-01-09| 36|2021-01-08|  0.1|
| A2| 2021-01-10|  9|2021-01-08|  0.1|
| A2| 2021-01-11| 32|2021-01-08|  0.1|
| A2| 2021-01-12| 10|2021-01-15|  0.9|
| A2| 2021-01-13| 47|2021-01-15|  0.9|
| A2| 2021-01-14| 42|2021-01-15|  0.9|
| A2| 2021-01-15|  1|2021-01-15|  0.9|
| A2| 2021-01-16| 22|2021-01-15|  0.9|
| A2| 2021-01-17| 27|2021-01-15|  0.9|
| A2| 2021-01-18| 49|2021-01-15|  0.9|
| A2| 2021-01-19| 18|2021-01-22|  0.3|
| A2| 2021-01-20| 28|2021-01-22|  0.3|
+---+-----------+---+----------+-----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Comment: Thanks Steven, I went in a different direction in my actual code to avoid the cartesian products - but this works. thanks!